# Slash replace into blank space when pass a laravel route url into onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Here is my some code where I create a button at the backend side. And I have put an URL into the function. But on my frontend side url slashes are replaced into white spaces. I don't know why it is happening. Please Help me

```
$usrRows[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="' . $value->id . '"  onclick="SDelete("' . route('ajax-delete') . '", "' . $tableName . '", ' . $value->id . ')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" >Delete</button>';
```

[image: Text](https://stackoverflow.com/image.jpg)[![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Glg.png)

into onclick function, it shows me without slashes.

Comment: First: why arnt you using vue or conditionally show this button and route?
Second: are you escaping the slashes?

so http://127.x.x should be http:\/\/127.x.x

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "/" manually by yourself ajax public route does not give us "/" even if we can view in other part when we have public files.

```
$usrRows[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" id="' . $value->id . '"  onclick="SDelete("' . '/' . route('ajax-delete') . '", "' . $tableName . '", ' . $value->id . ')" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" >Delete</button>';
```